# How are runlevels from CentOS 6 chkconfig translated for CentOS 7 systemctl?

Tags: centos, runlevel, chkconfig

How would I translate the following command from CentOS 6 to run in CentOS 7?

```
chkconfig --level 345 dovecot on
```

My first guess is to type the following instead:

```
systemctl enable dovecot
```

But notice that there are no `runlevel` specifications in my first guess.  Is a `runlevel` of 3, 4, or 5 assumed?  Or do I have to specify it?  If so, how?

I read [this wikipedia page about runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel).

Comment: This might help: [Intro to Systemd Runlevels and Service Management Commands](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/794615-systemd-runlevels-and-service-management)